# QStrings not showing when debugging with Qt Creator on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, debugging

I'm debugging a Qt 5.5 application with Qt Creator on Windows 10 using MSVC 2013 compiler.
CDB Debugger is set up in Qt Creator and I can start the debug session. However variable contents of Qt objects (QStrings...) can not be inspected, I just get the memory location, size etc.
I expect I'm missing for debugging helpers or the [debugger extension mentioned here](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Creator_Windows_Debugging).

Any clues what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I temporarily deleted qtcreatorcdbext.dll, started debugger (forcing to diplay an error) and moved the dll back. Now everything works.
It seems there was a problem with the setup procedure, maybe because debugging tools were installed after Qt Creator.

Answer (score 0):

I had to update qtcreatorcdbext.dll in /lib/qtcreatorcdbext32 folder. My Qt creator installed separatly from the Qt pack so I copied the dll from the Qt installation/tools/qtcreator/lib/qtcreatorcdbext32 to the separatly installed qtcreator